# How to verify correct actionlib.SimpleActionClient setup?

Tags: ros, navigation, actionlib, simpleactionclient, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to create a `SimpleActionClient` in my Python service node using the following lines of code:

```
move_base_client = actionlib.SimpleActionClient('move_base', MoveBaseAction)
move_base_client.wait_for_server()
```

I've got this working previously but I'm now trying to implement it on a different system where `move_base` is already running.

The code just hangs when it waits for the server and I'm not sure why. I'd like to verify that `move_base_client` has connected to the `move_base` topic as instructed to begin troubleshooting.

Any ideas on how I might do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/393802/how-to-verify-correct-actionlib.simpleactionclient-setup?/) by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) on ROS Answers with karma: 501 on 2022-01-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to make sure the action server is running. Do a `rostopic list | grep goal` and look for topics ending with ".../goal". The entire "..." part is the name of the action server.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2022-01-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You may try to specify a timeout period for `wait_for_server`.
The following code will display a message if the connection cannot be established after waiting for 2 seconds.

```
while move_base_client.wait_for_server(timeout=rospy.Duration(2.0)) === False:
    rospy.loginfo("waiting")
    # other actions
    # ...
```

ref:
https://github.com/ros/actionlib/blob/noetic-devel/actionlib/src/actionlib/simple_action_client.py#L66

---

Originally posted by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) with karma: 1908 on 2022-01-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1